# Prove that the following are real numbers

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers

> 1. $$\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{\overline{z}}$$
> 2. $$z^3\cdot\overline{z}+z\cdot\overline{z}^3$$

1.$$\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{\overline{z}}$$
$$\frac{\overline{z}}{z\cdot \overline{z}}+\frac{z}{z\cdot\overline{z}}$$
$$\frac{\overline{z}+z}{z\cdot \overline{z}}$$
$$\frac{2Re(z)}{|z|}$$ which is real number as a division of two real numbers

2. $$z^3\cdot\overline{z}+z\cdot\overline{z}^3$$

$$\overline{z^3\cdot\overline{z}+z\cdot\overline{z}^3}$$

Due to: $\overline{z_{1}+z_{2}}=\overline{z_{1}}+\overline{z_{2}}$ and $\overline{z_{1}\cdot z_{2}}=\overline{z_{1}}\cdot\overline{z_{2}}$

we get:

$$\overline{z}^3\cdot{z}+\overline{z}\cdot{z}^3$$

Now we can say that we got the same elements and $(z=\overline{z})$ therefore it is real number?

Is the reasoning in both of these correct?

Comment: Showing that a number equals its own conjugate is a valid way of showing that number is real, sure.

Comment: Minor error in the first derivation:  $z\cdot\overline{z}=|z|^2$, not $|z|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively:

- $\cfrac{1}{z}+\cfrac{1}{\overline{z}}=\left(\cfrac{1}{z}\right)+\overline{\left(\cfrac{1}{z}\right)}= 2 \operatorname{Re}\left(\cfrac{1}{z}\right)$
- $z^3\cdot\overline{z}+z\cdot\overline{z}^3 = z \bar z(z^2 + \bar z ^2) = |z|^2\cdot 2 \operatorname{Re}(z^2)$

Comment: Short, simple and straightforward

Answer (score 1):

Put $z=re^{it} $ with $r\neq 0$.

then
$$\frac 1z+\frac {1}{\overline{z}}=$$
$$\frac {1}{r}(e^{it}+e^{-it})=\frac {2\cos (t)}{r }\in\mathbb R $$

and
$$z^3\overline {z}+z\overline {z}^3=$$
$$r^4 (e^{2it}+e^{-2it})=r^4\cos (2t) \in\mathbb R $$

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively/geometrically, inverting a complex number means reversing its angle and stretching/shrinking its radius:

$$\frac1{z} = \frac1{re^{i\theta}} = \frac1r e^{-i\theta}$$

Since conjugation is just reversing the angle ($\bar{z} = e^{-i\theta}$), when we add the inverse of $z$ and its conjugate, the angle will be 0 (since the angle of $\frac1{z}$ will be $-\theta$ and the angle of $\frac1{\bar{z}}$ will be $\theta$), so it's real.

---

For the second expression, first factor it as:

$$z^3 \bar{z} + z \bar{z}^3 = z\bar{z}\left( z^2 + \bar{z}^2 \right)$$

The first element of the product is obviously real.

Squaring a complex number means doubling its angle. So when we add the square of $z$ to the square of its conjugate, the angles will cancel out.

So the second element of the product is real as well. And the product of reals is real.

Answer (score 1):

If we know $z + \overline z \in \mathbb R$ and $z*\overline z = |z|^2\in \mathbb R$ and $\overline{\overline z} = z$ and $\overline {z*w} = \overline z*\overline w$   we are pretty much done.

1) $\frac 1{\overline z} *\overline z = 1$

$\overline{\frac 1{\overline z}*\overline z} = \overline 1 = 1$

$\overline{\frac 1{\overline z}}*\overline{\overline z} = \overline{\frac 1{\overline z}}*z = 1$

$\overline{\frac 1{\overline z}} = \frac 1z$ so

$\frac {1}{\overline z} = \overline {\frac 1z}$ so

$\frac 1z + \frac 1{\overline z} = \frac 1z + \overline {\frac 1z} \in \mathbb R$.

2) $z^3*\overline z +z*\overline{z^3}= \overline{\overline {z^3}}*\overline z +\overline{z^3}*z= \overline{\overline {z^3}*z}+\overline{z^3}*z\in \mathbb R$

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\frac{z+\overline{z}}{z\overline{z}}=\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}$$ if $$z=x+iy$$